# How to navigate from one ViewController to Other Programatically, without Storyboard in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, button

I have a button which is located on superview:

```
let buttonSignUp = UIButton()
self.view.addSubview(buttonSignUp)
```

When I press this button I want to go to another view controller scene.

Comment: you need to bind method on buttonSignUp's touchUpInside event, using buttonSignUp.addTarget() method. you need to specify selector in addTarget(), that will be called when you press button.

Answer (score 0):

First add the buttons TouchUpInside-event and bind it to a selector

```
    buttonSignUp(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Then implement the method "pressed", like this:

```
func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    let vc = UIViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

This assumes that your ViewController is in a NavigationController!

If you instead want to present the view modally, you can do this:

```
 let vc = UIViewController()
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        //Here you can write code that you want to run WHEN the modal present is completed
 }
```

Comment: If I want to go to SignUpViewController.swift where I have to write way to go to this view controller?

Comment: Instead of creating UIViewController, you just create SignUpViewController.

Comment: You should really follow some guide of how to start programming iOS with swift. Look here and see if you find anything that suits your skill level: https://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials